# Waiting for LVM initialisation in AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, lvm

I'm looking for a way to wait for LVM initialisation in an AWS instance. Ideally one which allows to wait for "all" VGs. I've got 4 VGs and 6 LVs to initialise and currently the cloud-init script does:

```
aws ec2 attach-volume ....
aws ec2 attach-volume ....
...
aws ec2 wait volume-in-use --volume-ids vol-id vol-id ...
udevadm settle
vgchange -a y
mount ...
mount ...
...
```

Unfortunately at the time when `vgchange` runs, only one VG is visible and the second `mount` command fails.

Is there a good way to wait for the LVs in this case, without a manual loop of sleep / wait for `/dev/mapper/...` for each volume? The volumes need to be attached dynamically, rather than setting them up in the instance description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue after some time using very basic script:

```
for try in $(seq 1 20); do
  echo "Waiting for LVM to initialise ($try)"
  count=$(ls -1 /dev/mapper | grep -cv control)
  if (($count >= 7)) ; then
    break
  fi
  sleep 2
done
```

The `XXscan` commands on their own are not sufficient since all the present devices can be scanned after running the `attach-volume` command, but that doesn't mean all the required devices are present yet. That means all `XXscan` finish too early.

Answer (score 0):

```
pvscan
vgscan
lvscan
```

And i would add something like a `sleep 5` in there for good measure.